# how to fix unloaded images in "vue product zoomer" nuxt ssr

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

i successfully implemented vue-product-zoomer in my nuxt ssr.

when i come to this page through `$router` everything works fine

[image]

but when i refresh page something went wrong
here is screenshot

[image]

i have code like this

```
<client-only>
            <ProductZoomer
              :base-images="images"
              :base-zoomer-options="zoomerOptions"
            />
          </client-only>
```

and scripts

```
      zoomerOptions: {
        zoomFactor: 4, // scale for zoomer
        pane: 'pane',
        hoverDelay: 300, 
        namespace: 'zoomer', 
        move_by_click: false, 
        scroll_items: 5, 
        choosed_thumb_border_color: 'orange', 
        scroller_button_style: 'line',
        scroller_position: 'left',
        zoomer_pane_position: 'right',
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens sometimes and the only way that i found is to refresh the component, so do the following:

add key to your component

```html
<client-only>
   <ProductZoomer :base-images="images" :base-zoomer-options="zoomerOptions" :key=""key/>
</client-only>
```

on mounted hook increment the key

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            key:0,
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        // You may need to do the increment in a setTimeout (as for me doing it after 2 sec because of my skeleton loader)
        this.key++
    }
}
```

Hope it works.